# how to change textbox value from ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I make my own autocomplete in `html`, I use `ng-repeat` to show the suggestion. this is the code:

```
<div content-for="title">
    <span>Add Friend</span>
</div>
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="scrollable-content">

    <div class="list-group">
      <div class="list-group-item">
          <form class="form-inline" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="add.email" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email" auto-complete autocomplete="off"/>
                  <div  href="#" ng-repeat="x in cobas | filter:add.email"> 
                    <div class="media-body" ng-if="add.email.length > 0">
                    <h5 class="list-group-item media">{{x.name}}
                    </div></div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="addfriends()">Add</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what I want is, when I click the suggestion result, the value of that `textbox` is change to the suggestion result using `ng-click`, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add function in your controller, like below:

```
$scope.autocomplete = function (completeText) {
   $scope.add.email = completeText;
};
```

and then in html call the function on ng-click like below,

```
<div  href="#" ng-repeat="x in cobas | filter:add.email" ng-click="autocomplete(x.name)"> 
     <div class="media-body" ng-if="add.email.length > 0">
           <h5 class="list-group-item media">{{x.name}}</h5
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it work like charm, but how do I make the suggestion is dissapear when the value of textbox is same as the suggestion?

Comment: You can added ng-if on your ng-repeat div and set its value as false in the autocomplete() function. Then you have to $watch on $scope.add.email to show it whenever you start typing in the textbox.

Comment: `<div  href="#" ng-repeat="x in cobas | filter:add.email" ng-click="autocomplete(x.name)" ng-if="isDisplayed">`

Comment: `$scope.autocomplete = function (completeText) {
   $scope.add.email = completeText; $scope.isDisplayed = false;
};`

Comment: `$scope.$watch('add.email', function() { $scope.isDisplayed = true});`

Comment: it wont work sir, the suggestion didnt dissepear when i click it or already same with the value.